# Finding methods using command line

Tags: c

So I would like to run the program from the command line in the form:
(./program -f) or (./program -c ) depending on if I would like to convert a number from fahrenheit to celsius (-f) or celsius to fahrenheit (-c). The issue i am having is that i get errors/warnings. I believe my approach is correct but I am still developing my skills in c.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

float c2f(float c);
float f2c(float f);

float c2f(float c)
{
  return (9 * c/5 +32);
}

float f2c(float f)
{
  return ((f - 32) * 5/9);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  char c[3];
  char f[3];

  strcpy(c, "-c");
  strcpy(f, "-f");
  char **p = &argv[1];

  if(strcmp(p, c) == 0)
  {
    float returnc = c2f(atof(argv[2]));
    printf("%f\n", returnc);
  }

  else if(strcmp(p, f) == 0) 
  {
    float returnf = f2c(atof(argv[2]));
    printf("%f\n", returnf);
  }
  else
    printf("Wrong\n");

  return 0;
}
```

These are the warning I get:

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
char **p = &argv[1];

warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 if(strcmp(p, c) == 0)

note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2)

warning: implicit declaration of function ‘atof’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
float returnc = c2f(atof(argv[2]));

warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
else if(strcmp(p, f) == 0)

note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2)
```

I have ran my code and it just goes to default "Wrong" which means its not recognizing the -f/-c.

Comment: If you get error/warning messages INCLUDE THEM IN THE QUESTION!!! <yes, I am shouting>

Comment: What are the error messages and warnings. Edit them into your question.

Comment: @John3136 Thank you for the suggestions. I have added the warnings

Comment: Since when does `strcmp` take a `char**`?

Comment: Note that `5/9` is always `0` because it is using integer math. You'll want `5.0/9.0`.

Answer (score 1):

you had segmentation faults and other syntax errors. You also did not include a library. I have debugged your code and it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

float c2f(float c);
float f2c(float f);
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    char c[3];
    char f[3];

    strcpy(c, "-c");
    strcpy(f, "-f");
    char* p = argv[1];
    char* s=argv[2];
    float temp=atof(s);
    printf("%s value of p given and value of temperature %f\n",p,temp);
    if (argc<3)
    {
        printf("Please specify two parameters \n");
    }
    else
    {

        if(strcmp(p, c) == 0)
        {

        float returnc = c2f(temp);

        printf("%f\n", returnc);
        } 
        else if(strcmp(p, f) == 0)
        {

        float returnf = f2c(temp);

        printf("%f\n", returnf);
        }
        else
        {
        printf("Specify either -c or -f as parameters\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}



float c2f(float c)
{
    return (9 * c)/5 +32;
}

float f2c(float f)
{
    return (f - 32) * 5/9;
}
```

In future, please include the type of error or warning that you get so that it is easier for people to help you out.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now

Comment: Providing code only does not really help. What error did you fix? How? What was OP doing wrong?

Comment: The address of the argument argv was assigned to `char* p`. Also, `argv` should have been a double pointer. Library `stdlib.h` should have been included to use `atof()`. I have also included an if condition to check if the required number of parameters are being passed.